# How to make text blink in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make the text blink in react. I am a complete novice at React. So far I tried to make text red. The code is here,

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

class DisplayMyName extends Component {
    render(){
        const mystyle = {
            color:"red",
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style={mystyle}>
                    Deepesh
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DisplayMyName;
```

How to make it blink by using CSS attributes the way I am trying in above code?

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-blink-text

Comment: This isn't a React question, it's really a CSS question. Just google "CSS make text blink". Also, don't install a package like the above guy said, it literally only takes a few lines of code to achieve this, no need for an entire 3rd party dependency

Answer (score 2):

try out this npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-blink-text

OR include the following css in a separate file

```
blink {
-webkit-animation-name: blink; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0,0,0,1.0);
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <body>
        <style>
        .blink {
            animation: blinker .75s linear infinite;
            color: red;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        @keyframes blinker {
            50% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <p class="blink"> This is an example of blinking text using CSS. </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He's saying React!

Comment: Lets say you have a component ```App.js```. Then Create a file named as ```App.css``` in the same directory. Copy and paste what's in-between ```<style>``` tag and paste inside ```App.css```. Import ```App.css``` in the the component and use it as in the component as ```<div className="blink" > </div>```

Comment: I faced the same challenge without able to create a .css file, also the <style jsx> tag seems not to be working anymore